# Mi programa crashea al introducir cualquier numero despues del 10

Tags: c++

Para ver el error, cuando les pida el numero, escriban 10 o mayor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int sumalol;
int z=0;
int x;


int promedio(int digitos[])
{
int suma;

for (int i = 0; i < z;i++)
{
    suma = suma + digitos[i];
}

int prom = suma / z;

return prom;
}

int mayor()
{

}

int main()
{
int digitos[z];



cout << "Introduce la cantidad de numeros a recibir" << endl;
cin >> z;

for (int i = 0;i < z;i++)
{
        cin >> digitos[i];
}



cout << "Tus operaciones son:" << endl;
cout << "Promedio:" << promedio(digitos) << endl;
cout << "Mayor:" << endl;
cout << "Menor:" << endl;
cout << "Mediana:" << endl;
cout << "Fibonacci:" << endl;

}
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con que crashea, ¿qué tipo de error te arroja?

Comment: Un error con numeros negativos muy grandes, no tengo idea del error.

Comment: Mira, lo ejecute y no me tira errores como los que mencionas, algo que marcaba el programa es que no tenías inicializada la variable de suma. Puedes revisarlo aquí: http://cpp.sh/6ztpw

Comment: Declaras tu arreglo antes de tener un valor diferente de 0 para tu variable `z` tu instrucción `int digitos[z]` debe ir después del `cin>>z`

Comment: Tienes que asignar algún valor a la variable "z" o el bucle nunca llegará a ejecutarse

Answer (score 2):

El programa no debería ni si quiera compilarte, ya que estás intentando crear un array dinámico "int digitos[z]". Esa expresión no tiene sentido en C/C++ si z es una variable (no const). Tienes que reservar memoria dinámica para ese array (como se ha dicho en otras respuestas) de la siguiente manera:

```
int* digitos = new int[z];
```

Acuerdate luego de liberar la memoria:

```
delete[] digitos;
```

Otra manera un poco más elegante de hacer esto sería usando un contenedor como `vector<int>` que crece dinámicamente según lo vayas necesitando, pero eso es otra historia.

También he notado que te falta inicializar la variable suma a 0 dentro de la función promedio(). El codigo final te quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int z = 0;

int promedio(int digitos[])
{
    int suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
        suma = suma + digitos[i];

    return suma / z;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Introduce la cantidad de numeros a recibir" << endl;
    cin >> z;
    int* digitos = new int[z];
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
        cin >> digitos[i];

    cout << "Promedio:" << promedio(digitos) << endl;

    delete[] digitos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que obtienes la cantidad de numeros a recibir, `z` y no dimensionas tu array con este valor.

Debes obtener la cantidad de números a recibir, `z` y con este valor dimensionar tu array `digitos[z]` :

```
int main()
{
//int digitos[z]; Se define pero no se dimensiona correctamente.
cout << "Introduce la cantidad de numeros a recibir" << endl;
cin >> z;
int digitos[z];  //Se dimensiona correctamente tu array.
cout << "Introduce los numeros:" << endl;
for (int i = 0;i < z;i++)
{
        //Dimensionado correctamente tu array, ahora puedes introducir los valores de 0 a z.
        cin >> digitos[i];
}
...
...
```